# Flutter - Acess device all videos and images in Android 14

Tags: flutter

I am building auto backup app, where i can auto backup all images and videos, how to aceess device all videos and images by asking photos and videos permission, and now how to get video's, please help me till Android 14

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access all images and videos from a device running up to Android 14 (API level 30) in a Flutter app, you'll need to handle permissions and use appropriate packages. The `permission_handler` package will help manage permissions, and `photo_manager` to fetch media files. Here’s a brief overview of the steps and some code snippets to help guide you:

**1.Add Dependencies**
Add the necessary packages to your pubspec.yaml file.

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  permission_handler: ^10.2.0
  photo_manager: ^1.3.5
```

Then run `flutter pub get` to install the packages.

**2.Handle Permissions**
You need to request permission to access photos and media files.

```
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';

Future<void> requestPermission() async {
  PermissionStatus status = await Permission.photos.request();
  if (status.isGranted) {
    // Permission granted, you can access photos and media files
  } else {
    // Handle permission denial
  }
}
```

**3.Fetch Images and Videos**
You can use the photo_manager package to fetch media files.

```
import 'package:photo_manager/photo_manager.dart';

Future<void> fetchImagesAndVideos() async {
  // Request permission to access photos
  await requestPermission();

  // Fetch all media
  List<AssetPathEntity> media = await PhotoManager.getAssetPathList(
    type: RequestType.common,
  );

  // Iterate over the media and separate images and videos
  for (var path in media) {
    List<AssetEntity> assets = await path.assetList;
    for (var asset in assets) {
      if (asset.type == AssetType.image) {
        // This is an image
        // Do something with the image
      } else if (asset.type == AssetType.video) {
        // This is a video
        // Do something with the video
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**4.Handle Android Permissions in the AndroidManifest.xml**
Edit your **android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xm**l to include necessary permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="28" />
```

**5.Handle Scoped Storage for Android 11+**
For devices running Android 11 (API level 30) and above, you'll have to handle scoped storage. Consider reading through [Android's scoped storage documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage#scoped-storage) for more details.

**6.Build and Run**
After setting everything up, try building and running your app. Ensure that the permissions work correctly, and you are able to fetch images and videos.

***Note***: Always ensure to handle permissions gracefully and inform the user why the permissions are necessary.